# How to call a http GET and use the response in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, web-services, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I've looked at a few other answers and really can't get this working.

I want to call a lambda from Alexa - this is fine and gives me a response.  I want to base this response on a call to a http GET web service.  I have got the code below so far (updated to show the full lambda code):

```
/**

 Copyright 2016 Brian Donohue.

*/

'use strict';

// Route the incoming request based on type (LaunchRequest, IntentRequest,
// etc.) The JSON body of the request is provided in the event parameter.
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    try {
        console.log("event.session.application.applicationId=" + event.session.application.applicationId);

        /**
         * Uncomment this if statement and populate with your skill's application ID to
         * prevent someone else from configuring a skill that sends requests to this function.
         */

//     if (event.session.application.applicationId !== "amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.05aecccb3-1461-48fb-a008-822ddrt6b516") {
//         context.fail("Invalid Application ID");
//      }

        if (event.session.new) {
            onSessionStarted({requestId: event.request.requestId}, event.session);
        }

        if (event.request.type === "LaunchRequest") {
            onLaunch(event.request,
                event.session,
                function callback(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) {
                    context.succeed(buildResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse));
                });
        } else if (event.request.type === "IntentRequest") {
            onIntent(event.request,
                event.session,
                function callback(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) {
                    context.succeed(buildResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse));
                });
        } else if (event.request.type === "SessionEndedRequest") {
            onSessionEnded(event.request, event.session);
            context.succeed();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        context.fail("Exception: " + e);
    }
};

/**
 * Called when the session starts.
 */
function onSessionStarted(sessionStartedRequest, session) {
    console.log("onSessionStarted requestId=" + sessionStartedRequest.requestId
        + ", sessionId=" + session.sessionId);

    // add any session init logic here
}

/**
 * Called when the user invokes the skill without specifying what they want.
 */
function onLaunch(launchRequest, session, callback) {
    console.log("onLaunch requestId=" + launchRequest.requestId
        + ", sessionId=" + session.sessionId);

    var cardTitle = "Hello, World!"
    var speechOutput = "You can tell Hello, World! to say Hello, World!"
    callback(session.attributes,
        buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, "", true));
}

/**
 * Called when the user specifies an intent for this skill.
 */
function onIntent(intentRequest, session, callback) {
    console.log("onIntent requestId=" + intentRequest.requestId
        + ", sessionId=" + session.sessionId);

    var intent = intentRequest.intent,
        intentName = intentRequest.intent.name;

    // dispatch custom intents to handlers here
    if (intentName == 'TestIntent') {
        handleTestRequest(intent, session, callback);
    }
    else {
        throw "Invalid intent";
    }
}

/**
 * Called when the user ends the session.
 * Is not called when the skill returns shouldEndSession=true.
 */
function onSessionEnded(sessionEndedRequest, session) {
    console.log("onSessionEnded requestId=" + sessionEndedRequest.requestId
        + ", sessionId=" + session.sessionId);

    // Add any cleanup logic here
}

function handleTestRequest(intent, session, callback) {

    //---Custom Code---
var speechOutput;


var myCallback = function(data) {
  console.log('got data: '+data);
  speechOutput = data;
};


var usingItNow = function(callback) {
 const http = require('http');

 var url = "http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/IN";

    var req = http.get(url, (res) => {
        var body = "";

        res.on("data", (chunk) => {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on("end", () => {
            var result = JSON.parse(body);

            //callback({"email":"test","name" : result.name});
            callback('test');
        });
    }).on("error", (error) => {
        //callback(err);
        console.log('error');
    });
};

usingItNow(myCallback);




    //-----------------
     callback(session.attributes,
        buildSpeechletResponseWithoutCard("Testing Output " + speechOutput, "", "true"));

}

// ------- Helper functions to build responses -------



function buildSpeechletResponse(title, output, repromptText, shouldEndSession) {
    return {
        outputSpeech: {
            type: "PlainText",
            text: output
        },
        card: {
            type: "Simple",
            title: title,
            content: output
        },
        reprompt: {
            outputSpeech: {
                type: "PlainText",
                text: repromptText
            }
        },
        shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
    };
}

function buildSpeechletResponseWithoutCard(output, repromptText, shouldEndSession) {
    return {
        outputSpeech: {
            type: "PlainText",
            text: output
        },
        reprompt: {
            outputSpeech: {
                type: "PlainText",
                text: repromptText
            }
        },
        shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
    };
}

function buildResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) {
    return {
        version: "1.0",
        sessionAttributes: sessionAttributes,
        response: speechletResponse
    };
}
```

I have updated this code based on the reply below, but my test callback isn't even working, never mind the real one.  I presume I'm missing something...

Thanks.

Edit: here are my sample utterances and intents (all from an example I followed)

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "TestIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.PauseIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.ResumeIntent"
    }
  ]
}

TestIntent hello world
TestIntent say hello world
TestIntent to say hello world
TestIntent test
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to 'return' anything implicitly from http.get. Your response should return as a call back like below,

```html
var url = `URL HERE`;

    var req = http.get(url, (res) => {
        var body = "";

        res.on("data", (chunk) => {
            body += chunk
        });

        res.on("end", () => {
            var result = JSON.parse(body);
                       
            callBack(result)
        });
    }).on("error", (error) => {
        callBack(err);
    });
```

I have updated just the lambda function logic alone to get details from REST call. Please note it doesn't include build response for Alexa but just the REST service. Please find the same code below,

```js
const http = require('http');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    

        usingItNow(function (result, error) {


            if (error) {
                console.log('error')
            } else {
                console.log("Final result is"+JSON.stringify(result))
                callback(null,buildSpeechletResponseWithoutCard(result.name,"sample re-prompt",true))
            }


        });

};

var usingItNow = function (callback) {
   
    var url = "http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/IN";

    var req = http.get(url, (res) => {
        var body = "";

        res.on("data", (chunk) => {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on("end", () => {
            var result = JSON.parse(body);
           
            callback({ "email": "test", "name":result.RestResponse.result.name });
            //callback('test');
        });
    }).on("error", (error) => {
        //callback(err);
        console.log('error');
    });
};

function buildSpeechletResponseWithoutCard(output, repromptText, shouldEndSession) {
    return {
        outputSpeech: {
            type: "PlainText",
            text: output
        },
        reprompt: {
            outputSpeech: {
                type: "PlainText",
                text: repromptText
            }
        },
        shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
    };
}
```

and the result I got,

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Where would I put this in my code to get part of the response as a string?  I'll have a play around with it now.

Comment: I have updated the answer to put everything in your code sample.

Comment: Thank you again.  I suspect I'm doing something wrong as the callback in your code isn't working, but neither is the callback('test') that I used.

I will update my original post to show the full code.

Comment: speechOutput = getWebRequest.email; this is wrong. getWebRequest is expecting a callback. I will update answer in sometime

Comment: I've updated the original post with my code as it is now - I'm using a callback now but it's still undefined.

Comment: Your code needs a lot of cleanups. I will update when I get some time. Can you please share your  intents, sample utterances and slots (if you have), which help me to try everything in my AWS

Comment: I've added everything to my original post.  I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157367/discussion-between-vijayanath-viswanathan-and-ls-dev).